# PERL How to connect to SQLite database

Tags: perl, sqlite, internal-server-error

I have the following HTML + PERL code for connecting to the SQLite Database and retrieving a value, incrementing it, and updating this new value in the database. However, my code is giving an `Internal Server Error` when ran on browser. I'm using Apache Server. The error log tells me to check my html code but there's nothing wrong with it. Please help:

```
    <html>                                                                                               
    <body>
    <form action="/cgi-bin/a.pl"    method="POST">
        <input type="submit" value="Visit"/>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>


    #!C:/Perl/bin/perl.exe

    use DBI;
    use strict;
    use CGI;

    my $cgi = CGI->new();
    my $driver   = "SQLite";
    my $database = "my.db";
    my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:db:$database";
    my $userid = "";
    my $password = "";
    my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $userid, $password) or die $DBI::errstr;

    my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT cnt from VISITORS");
    my $rv = $sth->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;
    my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array();
    my $nov = $row[0];
    $nov++;
    $dbh->do('UPDATE VISITORS SET NOV = ? WHERE NOV = ?', undef, $nov, $nov-1);
    $dbh->disconnect();

    print $cgi->header('text/html');
    print "No. of visitors = ". $nov . "\n";
```

Comment: See the error log. The 500 error can mean anything.

Comment: "The error log tells me to check my html code" — that doesn't sound very likely. What, **exactly**, does Apache's error log say?

Comment: You might find adding `use warnings;` gives you more informaiton.

Comment: Don't you need `UPDATE VISITORS SET cnt = ? WHERE cnt = ?`

Comment: Also, what happens if you just run your Perl script from the commandline without Apache?

Comment: Any luck getting this working yet?

Comment: No. Still same error

Answer (score 0):

My error was that I had not create the table and thus it could not recognize the name of table and the insert statement failed.